# What happened to my question asking about the integral closure of an algebra of finite type over the ring of algebraic integers?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, deleted-questions, auto-delete

What happened to my question asking about the following question?
It seems to be deleted. Why if that is the case?

Let $A$ be the ring of algebraic integers in a finite dimensional algebraic number field $K$.
Let $B$ be an algebra of finite type over $A$ without zero divisors.
Let $L$ be the field of fractions of $B$.
Let $C$ be the integral closure of $B$ in a finite extension $M$ of $L$.

> Is $C$ Noetherian?

Comment: The question was auto-deleted when it reached negative score again.  Not to forget: that you run this risk was pointed out to you some time ago; you dismissed this advice. Here is a link to the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183087/integral-closures-of-algebras-of-finite-type-over-the-ring-of-algebraic-integers

Comment: Is there any documentation that OP was warned about this, and that OP dismissed the advice? There's no evidence of this at the site of the question itself. Was there a discussion elsewhere?

Comment: Perhaps this? http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/20399/18398

Comment: @Gerry Also [his previous meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/20386/what-happened-to-my-question-on-discrete-valuation-rings)..

Comment: @quid "*The question was auto-deleted when it reached negative score again.*" I was well aware of the possibility. But how could I be sure of it?
I wouldn't open this thread if I was certain.

Comment: By looking at the question.

Comment: @quid I forgot the title.

Comment: It was linked on meta from your earlier request.

Comment: @quid You seem to take it for granted that I am well versed  in this site which is not the case. In any case, they said there was no deleted question(there was a link which showed all the deleted questions in my profile).

Comment: Someone downvoted the question(http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183087/integral-closures-of-algebras-of-finite-type-over-the-ring-of-algebraic-integers) so that it has a negative vote right now.
It seems that he(or she) really hates me. **SHAME ON HIM!**

Comment: I do not take anything for granted, but I'd  assume or at least hope that users pay attention to explanations they received,  and are able to recall this information for some time, or if not  consult it again when the need arises before asking again. But as you see I even explain things again. But if you find this somehow hostile, I can stop all explanations. You got explained  the lists shows deleted *recent* questions, meaning 60 days past being asked. That question was not *recent* anymore.  Thus, it did not show in the list.

Comment: This thread got 8 downvotes. What does it mean? It seems as if I was the one who should be blamed instead of those who downvoted the legit mathematical question.

Answer (score 9):

> The question was auto-deleted when it reached negative score again.  Not to forget: that you run this risk was pointed out to you some time ago; you dismissed this advice. Here is a link to the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183087/integral-closures-of-algebras-of-finite-type-over-the-ring-of-algebraic-integers

Comment: "*you dismissed this advice.*" What do you mean? I have no idea what I should do to prevent some users from downvoting the legit question.
Please keep in mind that any user can downvote for whatever reason.